# Problem changing Java version using alternatives

Tags: java, rhel5

I'm not quite sure how I got into this mess, but for some reason I'm not able to change the current version of Java using alternatives.  I can run alternatives --config java and type my selection but when I echo the version number for either java or javac, it spits back out 1.5 every time (despite alternatives showing the current version is 1.6).  The server I'm working with is running RHEL5, by the way.

I have verified that the paths used in alternatives are pointing to the correct directories.  Here's some output from my session:

> [brilewis@myserver]$ sudo
>   /usr/sbin/update-alternatives --config
>   java
>
> There are 3 programs which provide
>   'java'.
>
> ### Selection    Command
>
> **  1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java
>   +   2           /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10/bin/java
>       3           /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java
>
> Enter to keep the current
>   selection[+], or type selection number: 3
>
> [brilewis@myserver]$ java -version
>
> java version "1.5.0_10" Java(TM) 2 Runtime
>   Environment, Standard Edition (build
>   1.5.0_10-b03) Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_10-b03, mixed mode)
>
> [brilewis@myserver]$ sudo /usr/sbin/update-alternatives --config java
>
> There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.
>
> ### Selection    Command
>
> **  1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java
>        2           /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10/bin/java
>   +   3           /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java
>
> Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:

UPDATE: The following is the output of `echo $PATH`:

> /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.24:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/NX/bin:/home/brilewis/bin

UPDATE (4/26/10): I followed Bert's suggestion and removed JAVA_HOME from the PATH environment var in /etc/profile.  After doing this, I was able to use alternatives to change the version of Java.  The only problem is that when I try to run `javac`, I get "-bash: javac: command not found".  This does not happen when the version is set to 1.5.

Comment: Do a `which java` to find out which physical java executable is being run! Is it possible you have a local shell script or `alias` shortcutting directly to one of your javas?

Comment: which java gives me: /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10/bin/java.  I don't believe there are any scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I was able to solve the problem was to start over again by removing /var/lib/alternatives/java and installing each JDK again.  I did the same for javac and jar.  After doing this, I was able to switch between versions without any issues.

Answer (score 32):

For Oracle Java 6u30, once you've installed their RPMs you can configure alternatives:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/java/default/bin/java" 2 \
--slave /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/default/bin/javac \
--slave /usr/bin/javadoc javadoc /usr/java/default/bin/javadoc \
--slave /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/default/bin/jar \
--slave /usr/bin/keytool keytool /usr/java/default/bin/keytool \
--slave /usr/bin/orbd orbd /usr/java/default/bin/orbd \
--slave /usr/bin/pack200 pack200 /usr/java/default/bin/pack200 \
--slave /usr/bin/rmid rmid /usr/java/default/bin/rmid \
--slave /usr/bin/rmiregistry rmiregistry /usr/java/default/bin/rmiregistry \
--slave /usr/bin/servertool servertool /usr/java/default/bin/servertool \
--slave /usr/bin/tnameserv tnameserv /usr/java/default/bin/tnameserv \
--slave /usr/bin/unpack200 unpack200 /usr/java/default/bin/unpack200 \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz java.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/java.1.gz \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/keytool.1.gz keytool.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/keytool.1.gz \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/orbd.1.gz orbd.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/orbd.1.gz \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/pack200.1.gz pack200.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/pack200.1.gz \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/rmid.1.gz rmid.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/rmid.1.gz \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz rmiregistry.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/servertool.1.gz servertool.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/servertool.1.gz \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/tnameserv.1.gz tnameserv.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/tnameserv.1.gz \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/unpack200.1.gz unpack200.1.gz /usr/java/default/man/man1/unpack200.1.gz
```

Then activate the configuration:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

And select /usr/java/default/bin/java from the menu.

Plus you must gzip the man pages

```
gzip /usr/java/default/man/man1/*.1
```

Also, the Oracle java RPMs might have clobbered your alternatives symlink so force it to be normal.

```
ln -sf /etc/alternatives/java /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: what about `javac`, `javaws` and other binaries shipped within jdk/jre?

Answer (score 9):

I can change the default Java on CentOS using these steps:

1. Add  the IBM JDK:

   ```
   alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java 3
   ```
2. Set the new IBM JDK as default:

   ```
   alternatives --config java   (then select #3 in the list)
   ```
3. Type `java -version` at the prompt to see the result.

Answer (score 4):

`alternatives` works by changing a symlink in the `/usr/bin` directory.  However, if your path contains a valid executable earlier in the path, that will be used instead.

In this case, judging from your previous comments, it sounds like `/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10/bin` is somewhere in the path and should be removed.

For a BASH shell, the path is usually set in `~/.bashrc` or (less likely?)  `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I do have JAVA_HOME in my PATH environment variable (not sure if that's the "path" you're referring to), but this didn't cause me any problems before when I used alternatives.  I checked those two files (bashrc and bash_profile, but there was nothing in them referring to the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated with more explanations**

1. Check which `java` executable is really running, e.g.

   `$ type java`

   If this shows something other than `/usr/bin/java`, then you've likely got a specific JRE/JDK hardcoded in your path.  This is fine, but you won't be able to use change Java versions using RH alternatives for any account that hardcodes a specific JRE/JDK in its `PATH` in this way. However, other packages/accounts (e.g. system processes) that don't hardcode a specific JDK version into its path will use the `alternatives`-specified JRE.
2. Check your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, e.g.

   `$ echo $JAVA_HOME`

   If this is set, this will sometimes point the java executable at a different JRE/JDK, regardless of where the `java` executable itself lives.  Again, its not unusual to set this, but you won't be able to use change Java versions using RH alternatives for any account that hardcodes a different JAVA_HOME.

All that said, for development in my account, I normally set a specific JDK in my path and set JAVA_HOME to point to a specific JDK, rather than rely on the system settings.  RH alternatives is fine to control what Java version other packages use, but for my own development, I like to explicitly target the Java I want to use.

Comment: 1. java is hashed (/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10/bin/java)
2. JAVA_HOME is set to /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10

Comment: @Brian - okay, sounds like `/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10` is hardcoded into your path before /usr/bin, so setting RH alternatives won't do anything while the `PATH` is set that way.  For consistency, I would ask that you add update your question to show your PATH. Then take`/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10` out of your `PATH`.  The see what `java -version` gives.  If it still gives J1.5 despite the `alternatives` setting, clear your JAVA_HOME env variable and test it again.

Comment: @Bert - I updated my question.  I also tried out your suggestion and removed $JAVA_HOME from my $PATH env var.  When I reconnected to the server and executed `java -version`, I got v1.6 this time.  However, now the problem is that `javac` gives me "-bash: javac: command not found".

Comment: @Brian `/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --config javac` - based on looking at http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_SOA_Platform/5.0.0/html/Getting_Started_Guide/appe-install_jdk_rhel.html - Run alternatives for `jar` too

Comment: @Bert - when I execute `/usr/sbin/alternatives --config javac` I don't get a prompt like when I do the same for java.  I get nothing for jar as well.

Comment: @Brian - kind of weird - is `jar` broken like `javac` or does it work?    Unfortunately, I don't have access to an RHEL5 system to investigate further.  I'd update your question again with the info from our last few comments to garner some other responses.

Answer (score 0):

When using the alternatives method, if you want to use an alternative, it must first be installed. I believe RPMs would include this as a part of the install, but in the case where manual installs are performed, you can still manually install. For example, with java,

```
alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/java/example/bin/java" \
 --slave /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/example/bin/javac \
 ...
```

What this does is to install an alternative for the java symlink. For each slave, it also builds/updates the symlink to some other value specified in another alternative, when you switch it. So if you were to switch to a different version of java using alternatives, and the alternative specifies a slave for javac, javac will repoint to the new version as well.

My full list is as follows:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/<version>/bin/java 1500 \
  --slave /usr/bin/ControlPanel ControlPanel /usr/java/<version>/jre/bin/ControlPanel \
   --slave /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/<version>/bin/jar \
   --slave /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/<version>/bin/javac \
   --slave /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/<version>/bin/javaws \
   --slave /usr/bin/jcontrol jcontrol /usr/java/<version>/bin/jcontrol \
   --slave /usr/bin/keytool keytool /usr/java/<version>/bin/keytool \
   --slave /usr/bin/orbd orbd /usr/java/<version>/bin/orbd \
   --slave /usr/bin/pack200 pack200 /usr/java/<version>/bin/pack200 \
   --slave /usr/bin/policytool policytool /usr/java/<version>/bin/policytool \
   --slave /usr/bin/rmid rmid /usr/java/<version>/bin/rmid \
   --slave /usr/bin/rmiregistry rmiregistry /usr/java/<version>/bin/rmiregistry \
   --slave /usr/bin/servertool servertool /usr/java/<version>/bin/servertool \
   --slave /usr/bin/tnameserv tnameserv /usr/java/<version>/bin/tnameserv \
   --slave /usr/bin/unpack200 unpack200 /usr/java/<version>/bin/unpack200 \
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/java.1 java.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/java.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1 javac.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/javac.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javaws.1 javaws.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/javaws.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/keytool.1 keytool.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/keytool.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/orbd.1 orbd.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/orbd.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/pack200.1 pack200.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/pack200.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/policytool.1 policytool.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/policytool.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/rmid.1 rmid.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/rmid.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/rmiregistry.1 rmiregistry.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/rmiregistry.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/servertool.1 servertool.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/servertool.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/tnameserv.1 tnameserv.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/tnameserv.1  \ 
   --slave /usr/share/man/man1/unpack200.1 unpack200.1 /usr/java/<version>/man/man1/unpack200.1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you have a lot of slaves.. :)